# Set values in application.conf with Docker

Tags: scala, docker, configuration, docker-compose

Neo4j database is used in my application and its credentials are defined in the application.conf file which is stored in project_folder/configs. I have created a Dockerfile for the project along with docker-compose file and I would like to change neo4j connection URL as environment parameter in docker-compose. How can I change the field value in the application.conf file using docker-compose or Dockerfile?

Here is how configs file looks like:

```
neo4j{
    url= "bolt://localhost:7687"
    user = "user"
    password = "password"
}
```

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  neo4j_db:
    image: neo4j:latest
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7473:7473"
      - "7687:7687"
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import
      - $HOME/neo4j/data:/neo4j/data
      - $HOME/neo4j/conf:/neo4j/conf
      - $HOME/neo4j/logs:/neo4j/logs
    environment:
      - NEO4J_dbms_active__database=graph.db
  benchmarks:
    image: "image_name"
    volumes:
      - ./:/workdir1
    working_dir: /workdir1
    links:
      - neo4j_db
```

Application Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.11.8
ENV SBT_VERSION 1.1.1
ENV SPARK_VERSION 2.2.0
ENV SPARK_DIST spark-$SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop2.6
ENV SPARK_ARCH $SPARK_DIST.tgz
ENV NEO4J_CONFIG neo4j_local
ENV BENCHMARK_NAME read_spark_single

WORKDIR /opt

# Install Scala
RUN \
  cd /root && \
  curl -o scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/$SCALA_VERSION/scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz && \
  tar -xf scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz && \
  rm scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz && \
  echo >> /root/.bashrc && \
  echo 'export PATH=~/scala-$SCALA_VERSION/bin:$PATH' >> /root/.bashrc

# Install SBT
RUN \
  curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb

# Install Spark
RUN \
    cd /opt && \
    curl -o $SPARK_ARCH http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/$SPARK_ARCH && \
    tar xvfz $SPARK_ARCH && \
    rm $SPARK_ARCH && \
    echo 'export PATH=$SPARK_DIST/bin:$PATH' >> /root/.bashrc

EXPOSE 9851 9852 4040 7474 7473 7687

VOLUME /workdir1

CMD /workdir1/runapp.sh "$NEO4J_CONFIG" "$BENCHMARK_NAME"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple approaches for doing this but since you are already asking for doing it with env variables change the application.yaml like following:

```
neo4j {
    url = "bolt://${HOSTNAME}"
    user = "user"
    password = "password"
}
```

and set the variable in docker compose by adding:

```
environment:
  - HOSTNAME=localhost:4567
```

This will work as long as you provide HOSTNAME env. variable, it will fail to load application config otherwise.

If you want to keep a default value for some reason use this:

```
neo4j {
    url = "bolt://localhost:4567"
    url = ${?HOSTNAME}
    user = "user"
    password = "password"
}
```

and pass a proper HOSTNAME env. variable with docker-compose file. This config will pickup if it is defined; will default to the first value if none is provided.

For detailed information check:
https://github.com/lightbend/config

Comment: Should I set this environment variable in my Dockerfile somehow?

Comment: @Cassie no, docker-compose will pass this variable when running the application